# Type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>' has no call signatures.ts(2349)

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create a form to add more admins to my project.

```
async addAdmin() {

    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(this.db, "admin-requests"));
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      if (doc.data().email === this.addAdminFormGroup.controls.adminEmail.value) {
        setDoc(doc(this.db, "admins", doc.data().uid), {
          name: doc.data().name,
          email: doc.data().email,
          uid: doc.data().uid
        });
      }
    }); 
  }
```

setDoc(**doc**(...

doc part is giving me an error that is:

(parameter) doc: QueryDocumentSnapshot DocumentData

This expression is not callable.
Type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot DocumentData ' has no call signatures.ts(2349)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was using doc name for both forEach document and for the function.

Changed the forEach document name for fixing the problem and snapshot name for more readability.

**Correct way:**

```
async addAdmin() {

    const adminRequestsSnapshot = await getDocs(collection(this.db, "admin-requests"));
    adminRequestsSnapshot.forEach((adminRequestDoc) => {
      if (adminRequestDoc.data().email === this.addAdminFormGroup.controls.adminEmail.value) {
        setDoc(doc(this.db, "admins", adminRequestDoc.data().uid), {
          name: adminRequestDoc.data().name,
          email: adminRequestDoc.data().email,
          uid: adminRequestDoc.data().uid
        });
      }
    }); 
  }
```